# Why are military uniforms often flared or poofy above the knee?

Tags: world-war-two, military, fashion, uniform

I've often wondered why do various uniforms have those "poofs" on the outsides of the legs just above the knee? Was there a particular purpose to this, or a practical reason, or was it just the result of uniform designers saying "Hey, I kinda like poofs."

I think it has also been seen in other areas as well. For example, on the poster/cover for the 1970 movie Patton you can see a similar design, though much more pronounced it seems (though that could just be Hollywood exaggeration).

> [image]
>   <sub>[Image Source](http://www.usmbooks.com/images/ORGbk/Orgbk6.jpg) (broken)</sub>

> [image: movie poster for 'Patton']
>   <sub>[Image Source](http://happyotter666.blogspot.com/2014/04/patton-1970.html)</sub>

Comment: We need a "poofy pants" tag.

Comment: If WWII=="medium level violence" , what does the MPAA consider high levels of violence?

Comment: I shouldn't really need to note that Patton was NOT a Nazi.

Comment: The Red Army also used them. In Russian they are called by a word "galife" after French general Gaston [Alexandre Auguste de Galliffet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaston_Alexandre_Auguste,_Marquis_de_Galliffet). He is the man who [originally ordered their use](http://lt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galif%C4%97).

Comment: "Hey, I kinda like poofs." - British viewers are going to get a good giggle out of that.

Comment: @canadiancreed - Yes I was about to flag the original question as offensive language before it occurred to me they might not have meant it like that.

Comment: +1 for the origin. I hope you don't mind my small edit, its a different language wikipedia page but when translated to English he is now General G. Riding Breeches bwaha. His wiki page didnt mention him as the inventor (unless i misread it)

Comment: Russian wiki does (not sure about invention, but first to order to implement them).

Comment: No, there was no offence meant in the question.  :)  .. What particularly was what caused the pondering of "offensive", though? Out of curiosity.

Comment: Yes that is what I meant to say. I can't edit it now though thanks for calling me out on it.

Comment: "Poof" is UK slang for homosexual - so "poofy pants" is a slightly childish way of saying "gay pants".

Comment: Ah; yeah... I'm in the US. Had no idea that was British slang.

Comment: Don't ask, don't tell!

Comment: @Anixx - as a possible experiment - go into a bar in London, find someone with lively cheerful clothes like a football strip and tell them they look gay.

Comment: Note to readers: This question was asked in [American English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_English), and thus uses its terms for articles of clothing.

Comment: Two nations divided by a common language!

Comment: And *"pants"* are what Brits wear **under** their trousers/skirts!  ;-)

Comment: "Gay" originally meant "happy, merry" but was borrowed (hijacked!) by the LGBT community to counter all the negative epithets - like "pouf".

Comment: @none - not unless you want a (British) punch on the jaw! ;-)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

These are jodhpurs, a style of pants developed primarily for horseback riding. Their intent was to allow flexibility in the hip and thigh while the more narrow lower portion worked well with riding boots and didn't get caught up in stirrups.

Comment: Derived from traditional Indian riding trousers, hence the name. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jodhpurs

Comment: And as armies mechanized and riding horses into battle disappeared many pre-war horse cavalry officers, Patton for example, still considered themselves cavalry. Others, like the Wehrmacht, thought it looked cool and co-opted the pomp of the "elite" cavalry. Rommel, for example, was an infantry commander before WW2 but definitely took on the cavalry mindset. Fashion was very important to militaries in WW2

Answer (score -1):

Believe or not but this sort of pants were designed for cavalry in Poland by  company Colmex in 1920. Just before Polish - Russian war in 1921. This company still exist in Poland  but now is making  ge pyjamas . Accidently, few years ago when taking about this topic with grand son ( J. Bonczar)of the  creator on this company , he mention that  buffing was done for three reason:
1) Mainly because that normal narrow  trousers if inserted to high boots were restricting somehow wearer's movement. 
2) Also if wearer chose to not insert normal  pants into boots then his contact with the horse sides were not as good  .
3) Solders  like deep and large pockets which buffing allowed.

Comment: Do you mean that this style of pants was invented by Colmex or that they simply produced a particular variety of them?

Comment: Welcome to History:SE.  Sources to support your assertions would greatly improve this answer.

Answer (score -4):

The style became associated with the cavalry and as cavalry meant elite, everyone wanted to wear the flares.

Comment: What does this add that is not already included in the answer by @jfrankcarr?